# C# Com OLE Server

Tags: c#, .net, com, ole

I am trying to figure out the best way to interact with an OLE Server using C# .NET

i have found some code that enables interaction with COM+ that appears to work for the OLE server but I wonder if there is a more elegant or simpler way?

I require that it be late bound.

Code (as pilfered from elsewhere on the net)

```
// Code start
Type excel;
object[] parameter = new object[1];
object excelObject;
try
{
    //Get the excel object 
    excel = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");

    //Create instance of excel 
    excelObject = Activator.CreateInstance(excel);

    //Set the parameter whic u want to set 
    parameter[0] = true;


    //Set the Visible property 
    excel.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, excelObject, parameter);
```

Obviously in my case I am putting the name of my ole server in where Excel.Application is, but I have seen cases in EARLY binding where you can call the function directly off the object without having to go via 'InvokeMember'

Is this possible? Can I use Type to cast as object as my type?

Thanks.

Comment: It is called COM, not OLE.  OLE has been dead and buried for a while now.  This will help you find the tab in the Add Reference dialog.

Comment: Well apparently what I am trying to reference is an OLE Server it is certainly a ole application that is an .exe and is self registering...  I know that COM+ is born of OLE but this is an ole server.

Comment: Use the OLE tab in the Add Reference dialog then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use `dynamic` instead of `object` and invoke the members as if they were there. This will then be checked at runtime, and if the name is correct, execute it.

```
//Get the excel object  
var excel = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"); 

//Create instance of excel  
dynamic excelObject = Activator.CreateInstance(excel); 
excelObject.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at this from the add references.  It gives you useful access to Excel.
Microsoft.Office.Core
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

...

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Excel.Application app;
    Excel.Workbook workbook;

    app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    app.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(  openFileDialog.FileName,
                                    0,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing);

    return workbook;
}
```

Cells and worksheets etc can be accessed like this:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Item[1];
worksheet.Cells.Item[6, 1]).Value;
```

Comment: Doesn't adding a reference make the binding early though? Also Excel was just an example of a another ole server.